# Should we use Async / Await or Then Closures for avoiding memory leak?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, promise, async-await

I have this NodeJS application that is using too much memory. We are trying to track the source of the problem.

So I read that closures are bad for memory usage. The Garbage Collector has a difficult time to free memory used by closures.

Our code has many parts using promises like this one:

```
thenableFunction().then(() => {...}).then(() => {...}).catch(() => {...});
```

So after reading about closures I thinking to refactor everything to

```
try{
    let result = await thenableFunction();
    ...
}catch(e){...}
```

I am now wondering if we will benefit from this kind of refactoring or it makes no difference after all.

What do you think? Any good links you know explaining this?

thanks

Comment: I don't think this will affect memory usage.

Comment: What I have [found](https://kyrylkov.com/2017/04/25/native-promises-async-functions-nodejs-8-performance/)

Comment: "*I read that closures are bad for memory usage.*" - where did you read that?!

Comment: I'll let him speak for himself, but there are a few reported cases of somewhat obscure repetitive/recursive closure patterns that can create memory leaks. (See the links in my answer below).

Comment: @Doug I hope you're not counting the IE6 case (RIP!). And regarding the Meteor case, it's a really obscure edge case in play with a dumb GC. But we cannot generalise that "closures are bad" from this example. Otherwise, every data structure is bad for memory usage! Linked lists are bad! Seriously, one could probably reproduce that case with (much more inconspicuous) `async`/ `await` code.

Answer (score 1):

`await` is, in effect, syntactic sugar for exactly the code you're replacing (well, except that any code that comes after your code block is effectively also pulled up in to the then clause - which is how the `await` keyword effectively blocks execution until the `Promise` resolves).  So this refactoring should not really effect the memory consumption.

The specific answer to the question will depend on two issues.  First, whether the rewrite avoids closures (that are explicit in the original code), and second (assuming the answer to the first is yes), whether the garbage collector will fail to GC closures as well as it does whatever the Promise is doing (if its not implicitly creating closures).

I'm pretty sure the answer to the first question is no - that `await Promise` is indeed creating implicit closures.  So I don't think you're avoiding them in the first place.

And on the second question, from my reading, it sounds like closures only lead to bizarre garbage collection issues (i.e. leaks) in some particular cases:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-use-javascript-closures-efficiently/index.html

https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/

So unless your uses of closures match some of these patterns, I would think even in the case that your Promise isn't implicitly creating the same closure, you'll still experience similar GC behavior.

Comment: but isn't it easier for the Garbage Collector to identify what to purge from memory when not using closures?!

Comment: @VictorFerreira you can't not close over the variables in scope. Doesn't matter how you write your asynchronous function.